# Change focus sequence on next press button in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

My RecyclerView items contains three EditText.

I want to move my focus from first EditText to second and third.

Then after i want to set my focus on first EditeText of next RecyclerView's item.

This all process will be happen when i press next button of my soft keypad.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

just set the ime option to next in Edittext 
example

> android:imeOptions="actionNext"

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/gm_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/coldo_text"
        android:hint="@string/enter_title"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="pigc7"
        android:textSize="ads2" />
```

Comment: i used material edittext but not work for me.